# Decorator Pattern in Swift produces a SegFault

Tags: design-patterns, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, swift, decorator

I am trying to implement a simple Coffee Shop simulator in Swift using a decorator pattern.

I believe my implementation is somewhat correct, but when building the project produces a compiler error - SegFault.

I know Swift is still under development but I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong.

To quickly explain the code - I am trying to create a beverage of type Espresso and then decorate it with the Milk class.

```
//
//  main.swift
//  CoffeeShop

import Foundation
import Cocoa

protocol Beverage {
    var description:String { get set }
    func cost() -> Float
}

class HouseHoldBlen:Beverage {
    var description = "House Hold Blend Coffee"
    func cost() -> Float {
        return 0.89
    }

}

class Espresso:Beverage {
    var description = "Esspresso"

    func cost() -> Float {
        return 1.99
    }
}

protocol CondimentDecorator:Beverage {
    func getDesc() -> String
}

class Milk<B:Beverage>:CondimentDecorator {
    var description = "Milk"
    var beverage:B

    init(bev:B){
        self.beverage = bev
    }

    func getDesc() -> String {
        return self.beverage.description + self.description
    }

    func cost() -> Float {
        return self.beverage.cost() + 0.10
    }

}

var bev1:Beverage = Espresso()
println(bev1.cost())
bev1 = Milk(bev: bev1) //This line seems to be the problem.
//println(bev1.cost())
```

The problem seems to arise whenever I try to actually decorate the existing Beverage object with a new class.

Comment: You have declared `bev1` twice...

Comment: Sorry - edited. I was trying to bind it to a different variable to see if that works. It fails without the var as well.

Comment: It seems like a bug to me.

Comment: What do you get out of declaring `Milk` as a generic `<B: Beverage>` vs. just declaring the `beverage` property as protocol `Beverage`? Implemented the second way it will compile, and I don't see what is lost.

Comment: Thanks.I did not know that you can declare a property with a protocol type. That's why used a generic which would conform to the protocol. 
By using your suggestion I got it to work.